# How can I rewrite this procedure to reduce code length?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The below procedure taking more time to execute. how can I rewrite this code to improve performance. Kindly share your thoughts, I'm facing this problem from last 4 days onwards but I am not able to solve it.

```
        with (
                 [identityColumn] [varchar] (10) ,FileClaimNo  int ,EntityIDCode Varchar(20),EntityTypeQualifier  Varchar(20),PreviousEntityTypeQualifier varchar(10),Qualifier varchar(2),LineItemNo int ,REFQualifier Varchar(20),REFQualifierValue varchar(50)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi mac_s , if u observer the procedure clearly , i am using only one table called CMS provider and i am fetching data from client XML file and i am going to update that data from xml file and store it into cmsprovider table.xml file contains limited data only like 50 records per day. kindly observe the procedure once instead of question then u will get idea.

Comment: not to mention: execution plan, waits, hardware....

Comment: Mitch , kindly forgot about performance problem , i verified execution plan, index fragmentation level, primary key status and every thing , here we have to focus on alternative logic for the above problem.

Comment: marc_s , kindly try to change the above procedure logic and try to understood what it is doing.

Comment: @L.Venkateswara: "kindly forgot about performance problem ," - that's an idotic thing to say. And No, I'm not rewriting your logic for you.

Comment: 1) Rewrite the entire thing without ifs and use cross apply/where conditions where appropriate.
2) After doing all that, you now know that SQL is a mess whether you use it procedurally or in a functional manner. 
3) Pull all the data to your interface and do the calculations with a proper language like ruby.

Comment: "here we have to focus on alternative logic for the above problem" - my sides are still hurting.

Comment: That is just a piece of a SP.  Just a with ( and some columns

Answer (score 1):

It's rather tricky to give any good advice here - just a huge pile of T-SQL code, no explanation what it is supposed to be doing, no table structures, no information on indexes etc .....

The few vague recommendations I can make are these:

1. If the parameters `@P_CMSProviderxml` and `@P_CMSQualifierxml` are XML - make them of type `XML` (not `NTEXT` [which is **deprecated** and should not be used anymore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx))
2. Parse the XML into a temp table or table variable **once** at the beginning - don't do it five different times in your code
3. if this stored procedures is doing five things - it's doing too much. Separate it into five distinct stored procedures, each doing their **one thing** (and **one thing only**).
4. don't try to "solve" everything at once - try to decompose the problem into smaller chunks, identify problems, solve one at a time (like (a) parse the XML, and (b) define the updates properly etc.)

Comment: +1 good advice on a poorly asked question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `ntext` to `nvarchar(4000)`

if still slow, then set showplan_all on; the checking which statement have higher estimateio or estimatecpu

Comment: marc_s , i verified execution plan, index fragmentation level, primary key status and every thing , here we have to focus on alternative logic for code to  the above problem